# Issue with API call

Tags: r, post, httr

Im trying to send some data points to a web api using the following.
(Not sure about sharing the key so Ive left part of it out).

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

url = "https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner"
t <- 1:101
val <- 2*sin(2*pi*t/25) + 5*cos(2*pi*t/50)
val[1:3]
body.list <- list(datapoints = val)
query.list <- list(api_Key = "wtt****")
res <- POST(url = url, query = query.list, body = body.list,
            encode = "json")
a <- content(res, as = "text")
b <- fromJSON(a)
b[[2]]
```

This Results in an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

The following curl command works (Ive edited out most of the data points)

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    -d '[5.458,5.8064,6.018,....5,5.458]' \
    'https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner?api_Key=wtt****'
```

Any suggestions on getting the POST command to work ?

Thanks for the answer hrbrmstr. Much appreciated.
I tried the following

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner",
  httr::content_type_json(),
  httr::accept_json(),
  encode = "json", 
  body = jsonlite::toJSON(val),
  query = list(
    amplitudeMulti = "1.0",
    bartelsLimit = "49",
    minCycleLength = "5",
    maxCycleLength = "300",
    sortByStrength = "true",
    includeSpectrum = "false",
    humanReadableText = "false",
    api_Key = "wtt****")
)
```

with and without the line with content_type_jason() and received the following error in both cases

```
b[[1]]
[1] "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The
inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this
resource."
b[[2]]
[1] "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
'Double[]' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'."
b[[3]]
[1] "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"
```

As I understand it, when the body is a list, encode() provides the format of the list elements. Its not clear to me what to do when it is not. I looked in the httr source and there is an undocumented function body_config, but not sure about using this in the POST command. Any suggestions for fixing this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an API key (and you were 100% correct to *not* share yours) but their [Swagger API Docs](https://api.marketcycles.online/swagger/ui/index#!/MarketCycles/PostCycleScanner) kinda *lie* a bit about what they expect as input.

I used a fake API key with that endpoint in the online Swagger tester they provide (knowing it'd fail but still show the `curl` line) and populated the defaults to get a full idea of what the endpoint expects and it gave back this (the formatting is by me, it came back one one whole line):

```
curl 
  -X POST 
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
  --header 'Accept: application/json' 
  -d '[5.458,5.8064,6.018,6.0702,5.9472,5.6409,5.1517,4.4888,3.6699,2.7207,1.6732,0.5646,-0.5646,-1.6732,-2.7207,-3.6699,-4.4888,-5.1517,-5.6409,-5.9472,-6.0702,-6.018,-5.8064,-5.458,-5,-4.4632,-3.8794,-3.2798,-2.6929,-2.143,-1.6488,-1.2225,-0.8695,-0.5879,-0.3695,-0.2007,-0.0633,0.0633,0.2007,0.3695,0.5879,0.8695,1.2225,1.6488,2.143,2.6929,3.2798,3.8794,4.4632,5,5.458,5.8064,6.018,6.0702,5.9472,5.6409,5.1517,4.4888,3.6699,2.7207,1.6732,0.5646,-0.5646,-1.6732,-2.7207,-3.6699,-4.4888,-5.1517,-5.6409,-5.9472,-6.0702,-6.018,-5.8064,-5.458,-5,-4.4632,-3.8794,-3.2798,-2.6929,-2.143,-1.6488,-1.2225,-0.8695,-0.5879,-0.3695,-0.2007,-0.0633,0.0633,0.2007,0.3695,0.5879,0.8695,1.2225,1.6488,2.143,2.6929,3.2798,3.8794,4.4632,5,5.458]' 
  'https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner?amplitudeMulti=1.0&bartelsLimit=49&minCycleLength=5&maxCycleLength=300&sortByStrength=true&includeSpectrum=false&humanReadableText=false&api_Key=aaaa'
```

That suggests the docs are lying when it suggests that the `datapoints` value is named. It's not. That's likely what is causing your errors.

I ran the original, generated `curl` command-line through [`curlconverter`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) and it provided this as an `httr` template:

```
httr::VERB(
  verb = "POST", 
  url = "https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner",
  httr::add_headers(Accept = "application/json"),
  body = "[5.458,5.8064,6.018,6.0702,5.9472,5.6409,5.1517,4.4888,3.6699,2.7207,1.6732,0.5646,-0.5646,-1.6732,-2.7207,-3.6699,-4.4888,-5.1517,-5.6409,-5.9472,-6.0702,-6.018,-5.8064,-5.458,-5,-4.4632,-3.8794,-3.2798,-2.6929,-2.143,-1.6488,-1.2225,-0.8695,-0.5879,-0.3695,-0.2007,-0.0633,0.0633,0.2007,0.3695,0.5879,0.8695,1.2225,1.6488,2.143,2.6929,3.2798,3.8794,4.4632,5,5.458,5.8064,6.018,6.0702,5.9472,5.6409,5.1517,4.4888,3.6699,2.7207,1.6732,0.5646,-0.5646,-1.6732,-2.7207,-3.6699,-4.4888,-5.1517,-5.6409,-5.9472,-6.0702,-6.018,-5.8064,-5.458,-5,-4.4632,-3.8794,-3.2798,-2.6929,-2.143,-1.6488,-1.2225,-0.8695,-0.5879,-0.3695,-0.2007,-0.0633,0.0633,0.2007,0.3695,0.5879,0.8695,1.2225,1.6488,2.143,2.6929,3.2798,3.8794,4.4632,5,5.458]",
  encode = "json", 
  query = list(
    amplitudeMulti = "1.0",
    bartelsLimit = "49",
    minCycleLength = "5",
    maxCycleLength = "300",
    sortByStrength = "true",
    includeSpectrum = "false",
    humanReadableText = "false",
    api_Key = "aaaa"
  )
)
```

It's more verbose than required b/c it's programmatically generated. To fit it in your your original code:

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner",
  httr::accept_json()
  encode = "json", 
  body = jsonlite::toJSON(val),
  query = list(
    amplitudeMulti = "1.0",
    bartelsLimit = "49",
    minCycleLength = "5",
    maxCycleLength = "300",
    sortByStrength = "true",
    includeSpectrum = "false",
    humanReadableText = "false",
    api_Key = "aaaa"
  )
)
```

*may* work. Again, I just went by Swagger and cant' test it. You can likely remove all the defaults in the `query` bit, too. I like to pass them when I build packages that interface to APIs, tho.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I like the idea of a curl converter.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It was a couple of tweaks of the code suggested by hrbrmstr.
The following code works

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://api.marketcycles.online/api/CycleScanner",
  httr::content_type_json(), # needed to add this
  httr::accept_json(),
  body =jsonlite::toJSON(val),
  # encode = "json", # needed to delete this 
  query = list(
    amplitudeMulti = "1.0",
    bartelsLimit = "49",
    minCycleLength = "5",
    maxCycleLength = "300",
    sortByStrength = "true",
    includeSpectrum = "false",
    humanReadableText = "false",
    api_Key = "wtt****")
)
```

Thanks for the help.